# FXLauncher - How to update fxlauncher after javafx app installation?

Tags: maven, javafx

I have a Maven Java FX project and using fxlauncher for automatic updates on application launch. I want to update fxlauncher to latest version 1.0.13. Is it possible without re installing the javafx application ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, FXLauncher does not currently support updating of itself. If you packaged your application with a native installer you will have to run the installer-step to re-create the installer and ask your users to download it. All settings will be kept however, so it should be a minor inconvenience to your users.

To make your users aware of the new installer you can push a normal update with a notification screen containing a download link.

We are looking at ways to support updating of the installer itself for FXLauncher 2.0.